# fill spinner based on another spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i am new to android
i am trying to fill spinner 2 based on the value selected in spinner 1.
i am able to load the fields in the spinner 2 but the values are not getting selected.

here is my signup activity:

```
package com.example.ddubusmarg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUpActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputId;
EditText inputPassword;
EditText inputConfirmPassword;
EditText inputPhoneNumber;
// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.6/registrationjson/insertnew.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        //spinner creation
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.boarding_city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.ahmedabad_routes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.ahmedabad_RTO_boardings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter3);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // name
    inputId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); //id
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); //password
    inputConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); //confirm password

    //inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  boarding city
    inputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5); // phone number

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //confirming password
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String id = inputId.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String confirmPassword = inputConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
            String phoneNumber = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

            if(name.equals("")||id.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||phoneNumber.equals(""))
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field(s) Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
            }
            // check if both password matches
            if(phoneNumber.length() != 10)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PhoneNumber is not 10 digits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Does Not Matches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Inserting Record...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */

    //again spinner 


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        name = name.toUpperCase();
        String id = inputId.getText().toString();
        id = id.toUpperCase();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String city = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String route = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        String boarding = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();


        String phoneNumber = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route", route));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("boarding", boarding));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", phoneNumber));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "GET", params);

        // check log cat for response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }  

}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {

    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    //spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    //setting spinner2 based on spinner1
    String city= String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
    if(city.contentEquals("Ahmedabad")) {

        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
          R.array.ahmedabad_routes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    else if(city.contentEquals("Vadodara")) {
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
          R.array.vadodara_routes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}


}
```

kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have already registered listener once in onCreate() that is sufficient. Remove the registration again in the onItemSelected callback.

Recommended way which is more OOP style is to have different listener object. Now since you have same listener object(activity itself) for all three spinner, you need to write a switch case inside the onItemSelected based on view.getId() and do different action for each case.

code will look like below

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
switch(view.getId()){
case R.id.spinner1id:
 //do spinner 1 action based on pos and id
case R.id.spinner2id:
 //do spinner 2 action based on pos and id
case R.id.spinner3id:
 //do spinner 3 action based on pos and id
}
}
```

Comment: can u explain about parent view pos and id. i understand that adapter class is use to fill the string array content and on setting adapter to the spinner, it is populated with the give string array. spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() calls onItemSelected() method. after the spinner is set and user changes the selection a call is made to this onItemSelected method. i am not able to figure the view parent pos id. i did experiment with them, but i don't understand their functioning. please help me figure out the filling of spinner based on another spinner.

Comment: parent - The AdapterView where the selection happened.      
view - The view within the AdapterView that was clicked.      
position - The position of the view in the adapter.      
id - The row id of the item that is selected.

Comment: it is up to the developer how he wires the callbacks. he can make use of any/all in parameters. say for example - You have the data structures in your hand that represents the data. So you can used the position info as index to the data model to get the selection info from the user.